# Get image data of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible (by standard JS or some browser extensions) to get the image data of a DOM element?

I'm thinking of usage like:

- create an offscreen DOM element
- fill it with some CSS-styled content dynamically
- get its image data
- use the image data somehow:

  - as a background (decorative repeated text)
  - as a bullet-image (unicode bullets)
  - as a WebGL texture (magic!)
  - ...

Can this be done? Was there ever a proposal for something like this?

Comment: You mean get a 'screenshot' of what that content would look like and use that screenshot as an image programmatically?

Comment: @Tejs yes, except that I generally don't want the user to actually see the content on screen (until I present it elsewhere).

Answer (score 4):

The only method I can think of would be rendering the elements to a HTML5 canvas object. Which is difficult to say the least. One such rendering engine I found with a quick google search can be found at: http://www.isogenicengine.com/2011/08/19/rendering-html-css-to-canvas/

Others obviously exist including:

- http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/crazy-times-rendering-html-in-canvas

Once drawn to the canvas, you can retrieve a data url which can be used to set the `src` attribute of images and css, and most likely WebGL Textures with the following method.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Also, if you are targeting Firefox specifically they have a proprietary feature which does exactly what you want.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas

Comment: Don't forget excanvas for IE<9 compatibility ! good answer anyway !!

Answer (score 2):

Use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to get element on the canvas and then http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ to convert it to "data:" URL.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library for the image generation part of your plan.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('my-node-parent');
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node).then(function (pngDataUrl) {
    parent.removeChild(node);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = pngDataUrl;
        parent.appendChild(img);
    }
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsayen/8h13tmcj/2/)

Comment: This has the same problem which brought me here. I have a function which takes an image URL and returns the DataURL, but I ran into a "Access to image" CORS error retrieving the image from URL. But the browser has already loaded the image, and I would like to just 'get the image data from the DOM element' itself (which is the question, almost verbatim). However, `domtoimage` generates an "Access to XMLHttpRequest" CORS error, so it's getting image data from the server, not the client-side DOM element / cache.