# Obtaining base64_decode($artwork) from a web page <img> in a DIV and file in JavaScript and comparing them

Tags: javascript, file, dom, base64

I am trying to compare what is on the server with what is on the webpage by trying to figure out the correct coding for obtaining base64_decode($artwork) from a webpage  Please note  have another question on here in relation to checking this task with sql.

I understand I can get the one on the page at $('outerimg').innerHTML

Can I get the base64 code from $('outerimg').$('#np_track_artwork')

where

```
<div id='outer_img'><img id='#np_track_artwork' src='images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png' alt='Playing track artwork' width='200' height='200'></div>
```

I have to wonder if i am missing something in the reference to it like $('outerimg').$('#np_track_artwork').base64.value or similar?

also I am aware this below can be used. Is this a better way of referencing it ?

image.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAATEElEQVR4Xu2dC8x1RXWGH61ptQpivCBQDUSUioo3qsVqpFVsK7aVEMUqlRRNjAoNxsaaWFJrW1MvLV4Sb5EGRbyg4gWwamuoLaGKSJWCqCgWQ7FFBZTYimBpVtl/+vHnnDN7n5l9zuw9zyRf/j/51qyZ9ax5v3P27LncAYsEJDB7AneYfYQGKAEJoNAdBBJogIBCbyDJhigBhe4YkEADBBR6A0k2RAkodMeABBogoNAbSLIhSkChOwYk0AABhd5Akg1RAgrdMSCBBggo9AaSbIgSUOiOAQk0QEChN5BkQ5SAQncMSKABAgq9gSQbogQUumNAAg0QUOgNJNkQJaDQHQMSaICAQm8gyYYoAYXuGJBAAwQUegNJNkQJKHTHgAQaIKDQG0iyIUpAoTsGJNAAAYXeQJINUQIK3TEggQYIKPQGkmyIElDojoEaCNwfeAZwGPAo4IA1O/VD4HLgK8BHgLPX9DO7agp9dimtIqA7AvcE7g3cp/t30f+fOHJvTwdeDNw4cjvVu1fo1aeo6g7+AnAw8JDuJ/7/UGCPinr9beCRwHUV9WnjXVHoG0e+9QZLfU3eeiADOvBR4KgB9rMzVejzSWk81x4KPLr7iU/XfecTXnYkxwBnZnuZqAOFPq3EtfhpXCpD/wiMPSdQqq/F/Sj04kiXOpzC8+zmaGy+pWuBvTffbB0tKvS8PMQkz9HA4cCBLQ+kPIwbq313IF7BNVcUer+Uh4hP6GaY49l3v37VtKqMwF7ADyrr00a6o9BXYw4+IfDXAnfeSEZsZCwCVwIPGMt57X4V+uoMfaj7al57Hu1fmkDkMlbfNVkU+vK0HwvEyirLPAg8ATh/HqEMj0KhL2a2D/BVYM/hSK1RIYFTgedX2K+NdUmhL0b9h8DrNpYFGxqTQCyBPaTVSbhdYBX64iEWnwDHjzn69L0RAu8BTgRu2EhrFTei0Bcn54Juy2TFqbNrCwjs3KZ6FnCOlG4joNAXj4R4Pj/IQbJRArcClwCfAj4GxB9bSyECCn0xyPO61W6FMDft5ptALD/9bvez7P//CdzcNKkRg1foi+GeApw0Ive5uQ6Bfh24rDvdJf6NnyuAW+YW7BTjUeiLs3YccNoUE9qzz9cDFwMXds+xfk3uCW6qZgp9cebuNsHjh3ZNRH0J+CJwEXCpX4enKs2y/Vboy3neBPxsWdxFvPlpXARjW04U+vJ8x2aWN48wHHyeHQGqLlcTUOjL+dwX+E7mAHpwt5Q2043VJZBHQKGv5hfvdnPKw7t3wzk+rCuBbAIKfVyhxw64M7KzpAMJZBJQ6KsBfrnbELEu5hcA71i3svUkUIqAQl9NMq71eXoG7BB5iN0iga0SUOir8Z8MvCojQ/E+O85at0hgqwQU+mr8TwXOzchQvEq7q4tWMghatQgBhb4aY1wQGJstcsr+wFU5DqwrgVwCCj1NMPcVm+/S04y1GJmAQk8DVuhpRlpUTkChpxOUewiFn+hpxlqMTEChpwEr9DQjLSonoNDTCVLoaUZaVE5AoacTpNDTjLSonIBCTydIoacZaVE5AYWeTpBCTzPSonICCj2dIIWeZqRF5QQUejpBCj3NSIvKCSj0dIIUepqRFpUTUOjpBCn0NCMtKieg0NMJUuhpRlpUTkChpxOk0NOMtKicgEJPJ0ihpxlpUTkBhZ5OkEJPM9KicgIKPZ0ghZ5mpEXlBBR6OkEKPc1Ii8oJKPR0ghR6mpEWlRNQ6OkEKfQ0Iy0qJ6DQ0wlS6GlGWlROQKGnE6TQ04y0qJyAQk8nSKGnGWlROQGFnk6QQk8z0qJyAgo9nSCFnmakReUEFHo6QQo9zUiLygko9HSCFHqakRaVE1Do6QQp9DQjLSonoNDTCVLoaUZaVE5AoacTlCv0Q4B/TTejhQTGI6DQ02xzhX4McGa6GS0kMB4BhZ5mewnwsLTZUoujgbMy6ltVAtkEFHoa4aeBI9JmSy1eDrwmo75VJZBNQKGnEb4FeGHabKnFqcDzM+pbVQLZBBR6GuFLgL9Omy21+CxweEZ9q0ogm4BCTyP8LeDjabOlFtcA+2XUt6oEsgko9DTCXwQuT5uttLgHcEOmD6tLYG0CCj2N7meAW9JmKy2OBD6R6cPqElibgELvh+5bwP79TBdavQ54WUZ9q0ogi4BC74cv9xXbF4DH9GtKKwmUJ6DQ+zF9BfDn/UyXWsUjwP9k+rC6BNYioND7YfsV4Px+pkut4qv/VZk+rC6BtQgo9H7Y7gTc3M90qdVLM9/HZzZv9ZYJKPT+2b+1v+lCy9jBFjvZLBLYOAGF3h/55zMn1H4M/DyQ+wejf4+1lEBHQKH3HwrvB2LLaU7ZG7g2x4F1JbAOAYXen9rvAe/ub77Q8sFA7G+3SGCjBBR6f9x3A27sb77QsuYJuUcCsXc+NuAcCMS3jzHKj4ArgFhbcA5wLvDTMRrS5/8TUOjDRkPu83UNE3KP6AR9KPAQ4H7DEIxiHUuMTwG+0f0RiH+vdj6jHGuFPozl14AHDatyO+ttTcjtAzwbeB4Qjw9TKNcBn+welz41hQ7X3EeFPiw7U5qQuwtwFPDc7oScOw4LtSrrz3WHd1xWVa8m1BmFPixZU5iQOww4HngWEPMKcyk/Ad4E/DFw01yC2lQcCn0Y6RITcmPMvO8FHAucABw0LKRJWkesZ0yy51vqtEIfDj53Qq7UOe8HADGh1upR0hcCvwP8x/AUtldDoQ/PeQysnFdP65zzvkvUj+7EHQK/+/Cuz7JG7Co8eZaRFQxKoQ+HuYlz3uM5+ynAY4HHKepkkuJdfMyfXJ+0bNRAoQ9PfO4hFMvOeW/tOXs4+dU1/r3bNBSv5Sy7EVDow4dE6XPeHwrEkdLPAX5ueHessYNATNDFRJ1FoWePgVLnvMfRUq8EfjO7RzrYSeAk4I0iuT0BP9GHj4jcc96Ht2iNoQTGeIU5tA9V2Sv04ekocc778FatMZSAYt9BTKEPHT5Q4pz34a1aYyiBeA36q24Lvg2bQh86fG6zz100s16r1hpKIMQe225jM1LTRaGvl/44tnnu7GIjSWwd/XCh/eKx2CcmMuNTdt/1sK9V6+LuCLCm97zPfbCuNTJ6VIpTYuawpjx2g/1NtxX0ez3iLmUSd9HF4RYP7P59UeZqw1S/4lz+V6eM5vx7hb5edqcs9B8A7+sEHqe81FL2AN7Q7bwbo09xes5ZYziegk+Fvl6Wpij0uKf9ncAHK9/m+Xjgn9ZLS7JWPDJ8J2k1QwOFvl5SpyL07wPvAt7aHdO0XrSbrxWHZMQqt9hTX7JcAMStO80Vhb5eymuddY/bZGLTzTXAB7pP7ziwYarlL4E/Ktz53wbOLuyzencKfXiK4vy1ENK2S4j6S0DMKn8RuAi4tMDVUduOa/f247k6jsQqWeKKraZm4RX68OETRza/fni1YjVeCMStMXMU9SJId+6OhX5SMYK3PcrETH8zRaEPT3VMaMVpqpsqU33OLsmntNjjcSbOsf9KyU7W7EuhD89OTOjEwRBjlyuBaCv+qEz5ObsUpxB7XP5Q6jTbOIoqDvZooij04Wkee8Y9bjH5M+C9rT1H9khFicM5dzbzVOBve7Q7eROFPjyF53Xrp4fXXFxj10z5Dd2rMAW+mmzcNBMLfWJCLbfEjTCxOm/2RaEPT3Gs/47DDXJLPOvHaTWtTKrl8tpZ/1UFD4SMq6z/u2TnavSl0Idn5TjgtOHVblcjnjNrfRefGdpGqseRW3G9VYkSbzHeVsJRzT4U+vDsxHNifOVb98jnJwDnD2/WGrsRuG+h5azxByOur5p1Uejrpfdpa66uOrW7Q2y9Vq21O4G4nikmLnPLkcAncp3UXF+hr5+d0weeOPrt7jji2D1mKUMgJuRiMjO3xEafZ+Y6qbm+Ql8/O8HuROA1QLzjXVXe09nGzLqlLIESb0G2dZ11WRIrvCn0fNRxgEJcbnhw97Mf8EPg8m7lVazVPie/GT0sIVBicjRcx5zLtXOlrNDnmtl24sqdHN1Fatanxir0dgQx50jXnRzdyUShz3mEGNtsCOSuS1DosxkKBjJnAjHRmXOVtEKf8+gwttkQyN1spNBnMxQMZM4E/Oru67U5j29j6wgodIWuGGZOoMTFl351n/kgMbzpE4gFSbFePafcD7g6x0HNdX2PXnN27FsfAiV2sd0ExMKbW/o0OEUbhT7FrNnnXQRij0GJQyP+HjhizlgV+pyzO+/YQuTnAr9WIMzZHz6h0AuMEl1snECc0BMi/40CLcds/b2A6wr4qtaFQq82NXZsBYGXdduDS0D6DPDkEo5q9qHQa86OfVtEYC/gKmDPQniauItNoRcaLbrZGIFXAn9SqLW4uy5ubJl9UeizT/GsAoxP83/L3LyyE8jTgY/NitCSYBR6C1meT4z/ADyxUDjNfJoHL4VeaNToZnQCcUPLvxRs5deBTxf0V7UrhV51euxcRyBOe/1ydyZfCShnDDzBt0SbW/Wh0LeK38Z7Eih1fns0dw0QG1jiAM9mikJvJtWTDbTEWvadwc96l9qyLCv0yY7/Jjpeai37LlhNitzJuCa0Mtkg4yLFuCapxFr2gPDygqvpJgfVT/TJpayZDsedavFsXqI09SptETCFXmIY6aM0gXiV9gUgZttLlGYWxviMXmK46GMTBOIAiBsLNhR/MB5T0N8kXfmJPsm0zbbTsf30Rz0urewLIE6MeXh3B17fOrO0U+izTOtkg3o/cEzB3r8VeFFBf5N1pdAnm7pZdTw+yd/QXS1dMrB4xv9pSYdT9aXQp5q5+fQ73pXHDrKnFA6pqbXsKXYKPUXI349JIET+ue45umQ7za1lT8FT6ClC/n4sAnF809+N4LzJtewpjgo9RcjflyYQK97eATy3tOPOX7PLXFfxVOgjjTbdLiTwQODDwMNG4nM0cNZIviftVqFPOn2T6vyzu0/yu47U61cArx7J9+TdKvTJp7D6APYAvgHcZ8Sefg+I7ay+SlsCWaGPOPp0zbOAvwL2HZnFQcDXR25j0u4V+qTTV23nHwW8HTh0Az38A+DNG2hn0k0o9Emnr7rOPwj42gZ75RLXnrAVek9Qmq0kcG/g48Avb5DTFcAhwI832OZkm1Lok03d1jt+GHAk8AwgPsk3WT4JHAdcu8lGp9yWQp9y9jbf97gp5VjgBCAmwLZR/qLgyTPb6P9W2lToW8E+qUYP6CbVztxyr38CxCTfZVvuxySbV+jjpe3A7pPv4O7igXiffHl3CMJHgLPHazrL8/2BZwJHAI8teM9ZTqdi/fqTgK/mOGm5rkIvn/1gemJ34mjszlpWTgdeXPjYpHWiuWd3n1n0pdSJq+v0Y1mduDYpHhe+W9Jpa74UevmMfwiINdd9ytXdJ+emP6niU/t3gViWGuvOax0HIfDYcmrJJFBrgjPD2lr1GJjxST1GibPUvgVcAnwWiJtFh6wG2xP4feA5wC+N0cGCPmM+IPr6XwV9Nu1KoZdL/z7dM2QIalvleuBi4MLujrHo0+HA47bVoYHtxumvxwPxrchSkIBCLwfzpcDry7lrzlPclnpU962lueDHDlihlyP8TuB55dw14ylem/0p8Fogjme2jEBAoZeDegEQq8Us/QnE5QrxLO678f7M1rJU6GthW1jpvO55uJzHeXuKFW4nA7fOO8w6olPo5fJwCnBSOXez9XRld0XS92cbYYWBKfRySYlNFqeVczdLT/E1XUZbSK1CLwc9LgeMI5P2Ludy8p5i6Wos9X0X8M+Tj2bCASj0ssl7WsVr2MtGutpb3Hf2mYELejbZv+baUujlU/4++L+z0loq8bwdn9px4kt8q7FURkChl09IbGQ5p9ttVd57HR5v7pbixlfzDwAfBOJ9uKVSAgp9nMTMUeyx1v4lwEXApUCI3TIRAgp9vESF2M+tdOtnn6jj0zr2zb8XiMVAlgkTUOjjJi/E/lEgrvCdSnnBGjvjphJbs/1U6OOnvu9BFOP3ZHkLsYglzmCP3W+WGRJQ6JtL6u5HS+23W9NxT3isrotLCHe/WmjXKTCx5TR+SlxS+PnuWKu4lDAmDy0zJqDQ55PcODUmjl5+PPAIYP8Bf0jmQ8FIFhJQ6A4MCTRAQKE3kGRDlIBCdwxIoAECCr2BJBuiBBS6Y0ACDRBQ6A0k2RAloNAdAxJogIBCbyDJhigBhe4YkEADBBR6A0k2RAkodMeABBogoNAbSLIhSkChOwYk0AABhd5Akg1RAgrdMSCBBggo9AaSbIgSUOiOAQk0QEChN5BkQ5SAQncMSKABAgq9gSQbogQUumNAAg0QUOgNJNkQJaDQHQMSaICAQm8gyYYoAYXuGJBAAwQUegNJNkQJKHTHgAQaIKDQG0iyIUpAoTsGJNAAAYXeQJINUQIK3TEggQYIKPQGkmyIElDojgEJNEBAoTeQZEOUgEJ3DEigAQIKvYEkG6IEFLpjQAINEFDoDSTZECWg0B0DEmiAgEJvIMmGKAGF7hiQQAMEFHoDSTZECSh0x4AEGiCg0BtIsiFK4H8B2KFPGcGg0XAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";

I am using

```
var openFile = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var text = reader.result;
          var node = document.getElementById('output');
          node.innerText = text;
          console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
        };
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

and  the following to get the base file 64 encoded value is this the best method?

```
 function CheckResponse(transport)
{
    var content = transport.response.Text;
    var base64file1 = openFile('/images/nowplaying-artwork_2.png');
    var base64file2 =  $('outer_img').$('#np_track_artwork').src.value;
    
    if(base64file1 != base64file2)
    { // etc
```

would this be better?

```
var openFile2 = function(filename) {
    var r = fopen(filename);
    if(r !== false) {
        fread(r,artwork,wb);
        fclose(r);
        return artwork;
    } else { 
        console.log('Sorry could not read artwok.');
    }
    
};
```

Neither of these two functions above seem to return image contents can anyone help as am stuck ?

Well My CheckResponse Is firing so it must be this image retrieve rubbish https://i.gyazo.com/f4f0a3ea8a9fcddd864b420ddadddb21.png

If you look here https://i.gyazo.com/77c16c54f9cb91e1f1ef8be0d4fc7589.png You can see that it gets as far as ReadAsArrayBuffer and then goes back to timer why is this read routine failing?

**"Blob is not defined" fetching images"**
Oh the Google Inspection Debugger halts on  code  var file = new File([blob], "/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png",{type:"image/png", lastModified:new Date().getTime()})from stackflow that was to supposedly create a blob . I am either presuming there is no support for blob creation on 000WebHostApp site and this is new technology on github the code clearly fails with this error for unknown reason . I tried adding in canvas to see if it was a missing library but this had no effect . what are the options is there another way to read a file inn base 564 image into the JavaScript without these dreadful unsupported blob please. I have tried fetch this also fails?

**Without annoying blobs**
It was apparent to me from this that the security on https connection may be interfering with anything like this so i tried something different . Which no longer created and error but still did not do what was expected

```
 var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = '/images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png';
    image.id ='temp_image';
    var base64file1 = image.src.value;
```

Now the image gets created as an object but base64file1 is undefined as even though a create document image of 'img' item occurred. It does bot seem to have populated the base64 data idk why also issuing an  image.fetch(); seems to reproduce same catch error forcing reflow on this item not appended to page ?

I tried

```
var base64file2 = document.getElementById('#np_track_artwork').src.value;
```

This was also undefined according to local scope in Chrome Inspection debugger . in fact  base64file1 and  base64file2 are not defined on running this code.

I set a watch up on document.getElementByID('outer_img')

which returned the following elements:
document.getElementById('outer_img');: div#outer_img

```
accessKey: ""
align: ""
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
ariaColSpan: null
ariaCurrent: null
ariaDescription: null
ariaDisabled: null
ariaExpanded: null
ariaHasPopup: null
ariaHidden: null
ariaKeyShortcuts: null
ariaLabel: null
ariaLevel: null
ariaLive: null
ariaModal: null
ariaMultiLine: null
ariaMultiSelectable: null
ariaOrientation: null
ariaPlaceholder: null
ariaPosInSet: null
ariaPressed: null
ariaReadOnly: null
ariaRelevant: null
ariaRequired: null
ariaRoleDescription: null
ariaRowCount: null
ariaRowIndex: null
ariaRowSpan: null
ariaSelected: null
ariaSetSize: null
ariaSort: null
ariaValueMax: null
ariaValueMin: null
ariaValueNow: null
ariaValueText: null
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: id, id: id, length: 1}
autocapitalize: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "http://deniserose.000webhostapp.com/fetch_sql.php"
childElementCount: 1
childNodes: NodeList [img#np_track_artwork]
children: HTMLCollection [img#np_track_artwork, np_track_artwork: img#np_track_artwork]
classList: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
className: ""
clientHeight: 204
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 200
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
elementTiming: ""
enterKeyHint: ""
firstChild: img#np_track_artwork
firstElementChild: img#np_track_artwork
hidden: false
id: "outer_img"
innerHTML: "<img id=\"np_track_artwork\" src=\"images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png\" alt=\"Playing track artwork\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\">"
innerText: ""
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: img#np_track_artwork
lastElementChild: img#np_track_artwork
localName: "div"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "DIV"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 204
offsetLeft: 1
offsetParent: td
offsetTop: 1
offsetWidth: 200
onabort: null
onanimationend: null
onanimationiteration: null
onanimationstart: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onbeforexrselect: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerrawupdate: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
ontransitioncancel: null
ontransitionend: null
ontransitionrun: null
ontransitionstart: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitanimationend: null
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
onwebkitanimationstart: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkittransitionend: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<div id=\"outer_img\"><img id=\"np_track_artwork\" src=\"images/nowplaying_artwork_2.png\" alt=\"Playing track artwork\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"></div>"
outerText: ""
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: td
parentNode: td
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: text
scrollHeight: 204
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 200
shadowRoot: null
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {additiveSymbols: "", alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", …}
tabIndex: -1
tagName: "DIV"
textContent: ""
title: ""
translate: true
```

As you can see this is a valid element [img#np_track_artwork] I am unsure why it cannot obtain base 64 code hex value can any else suggest why as answer given by @Winter didn't resolve this i have to wonder if the reference is not correct? However looking through this division ID its hard to locate its data to check references?

I have been using the watcher to try and build a reference to the data of the image .

i.e

```
document.getElementById('outer_img') ;:div#outer_img
```

and

```
document.getElementById('outer_img'). getElementById('np_track_artwork') :<not available>
```

as is

```
document.getElementById('outer_img'). GetElementById('img#np_track_artwork'):<not available>
```

It seems anything under the div *outer_img* comes back **'not available'** does this mean the debugger cant evaluate it or there is nothing that can be accessed in javascript after the div *outer_img*. I see a lot of node things which are new to me which did not used to be there back in the day books I have inherited.

**New effort DOM**
I found a new article [Get image data of a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145676/get-image-data-of-a-dom-element) which looked hopeful from the coding

I tried var base64file2 =   $("img#np_track_artwork").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+data);

But the Catch system e: TypeError :Cannot read property 'attr' or null at CheckResponse at klass.ResponeToReadyState message seems to show this no longer function. Why is it no one has DOM parenthases that is workable to base64 image constructed on a webpage ? Have you all lost your way like me . I note goal posts are being altered to on your system as you now require 50 reputation to comment elsewhere  on wrong posts is it not a wonder none of this is not working by example?

**New Test**

I tried a previous version I had written that I had some success with this worked in the html file  but it did not refresh the image. until you hover over it.

```
   function updateArtworkDisplay() {
        document.querySelector('#np_track_artwork').src = 'nowplaying_artwork.png?' + new Date().getTime();
    //enter code here
}
```

Thanks for looking .

Comment: You are referencing `outerimg` several times, but in your HTML code it is `outer_img`...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will fix the entire issue, but when I get `undefined` in JS, I try to check if I really have access to the parent element first.

If the code you have pasted is the actual code you use, then you have an error on this line:

`var base64file2 =  $('outerimg').$('#np_track_artwork').src.value;`

According to your code it should be:

`var base64file2 =  $('#outer_img').$('#np_track_artwork').src.value;`

note the difference in how you get the `outer_img` from jQuery.